# Chipmunk: How to remove shape and body?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, physics, chipmunk

First, sorry for my English, im not an American. My question is how can I remove the shape and body from the space, this isn't related with collision detection. Im triying to do this with a touch event, specifically I'm trying to clear a ball Touching it (I have a lot of balls in the space), but I have no idea how to do it, I have been looking on Internet and cannot find any help regarding how to do it, all relates to the collisions and that's not what I need.

I read many times the documentation, but not contain any useful information how to do this. Only have how delete with colission. I know how delete with colission:

static void postStepRemove (cpSpace *space, cpShape *shape, void *data) {

```
//Remove the shape and body
cpSpaceRemoveBody(space, shape->body);
cpBodyFree(shape->body);
cpSpaceRemoveShape(space, shape);
cpShapeFree(shape);
```

}

static int collission(cpArbiter *arb, cpSpace *space, void *data){

```
     cpShape *a, *b;

 cpArbiterGetShapes(arb, &a, &b);

    cpSpaceAddPostStepCallback(space, (cpPostStepFunc)postStepRemove, a, nil);
    cpSpaceAddPostStepCallback(space, (cpPostStepFunc)postStepRemove, b, nil);
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

}

I use this with collision, but I need some example without collision.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Find the library documentation and read the damn manual:* [Chipmunk physics documentation](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/wiki/Documentation?tm=6)

`cpBodyFree` and `cpShapeFree` seem to be the API calls you need. Cocos2d likely has some bindings on calling them. Locate Cocos2D documentation if you need to know more about those calls.

Comment: Yes I know, but I read many times the documentation, but not contain any useful information how to do this. Only have how delete with colission.

Comment: Also I cannot remove a shape and body when cpSpaceStep is running. I need a post step remove but I dont know how to do this.

Comment: just create a set for shapes you'll remove after cpSpaceStep has completed. `dropped_shapes.add(shape)`, then free each shape added into that set once cpSpaceStep completes.